# Diff between two files

Tags: java, string, file, diff

I'm looking for a snippet of code that does the following:

Given two list of string representing two files

For example,

- FILE1 = {"SSome" , "SSimple", "TText", "FFile"}
- FILE2 = {"AAnother", "TText", "FFile", "WWith", "AAdditional", "LLines"}

If I call diff(file1,file2)

The output would be the diff between FILE1 and FILE2:

1. *SSome|Another
2. -SSimple
3. TText
4. FFile
5. +WWith
6. +AAdditional
7. +LLines

Many thanks!

Comment: Cant tell does i understand your q, but maybe you wqnt large "FILE" strings. to compare with every single string in less large "FILE" and print diff? Little sreaching and you shold bump into function String.equals to compare two strings

Comment: Everything else kind of makes sense but whats the logic for `*Some|Another`

Comment: You can just parse the file, add the lines to separate sets, and take the difference of the sets and other set operations to find out what differs. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather from your question the following:

- `*word1|word2` - Means the word from file 1 was changed in file 2
- `-word` - Means the word from file 1 was removed file 2
- `word` - Means the word from file 1 remained the same in file 2
- `+word` - Means the word wasn't originally in file 1, but was added to file 2

I figured file 1 is the "source" file and file 2 is the "destination" file for which we are showing these differences from.  Having said that, try this algorithm (It's not perfect to [DiffNow](http://www.diffnow.com) but it's pretty close):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> file1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Some", "Simple", "Text", "File"));
    List<String> file2 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Another", "Text", "File", "With", "Additional", "Lines"));

    boolean diff = false;
    int file2Index = 0;
    for (int file1Index = 0; file1Index < file1.size();) {
        if (!file1.get(file1Index).equals(file2.get(file2Index)) && !diff) {
            diff = true;
            // The word from file 1 was changed
            System.out.println("*" + file1.get(file1Index) + "|" + file2.get(file2Index));
            file1Index++;
            file2Index++;
        } else if (!file1.get(file1Index).equals(file2.get(file2Index)) && diff) {
            // This word was removed from file 1
            System.out.println("-" + file1.get(file1Index));
            file1Index++;
        } else {
            System.out.println(file1.get(file1Index));
            diff = false;
            file1Index++;
            file2Index++;
        }
    }

    // Print what's left from file 2
    for (; file2Index < file2.size(); file2Index++) {
        System.out.println("+" + file2.get(file2Index));
    }
}
```

Results:

```
*Some|Another
-Simple
Text
File
+With
+Additional
+Lines
```

Comment: *word1|word2 - Means the first word of the first file was changed to the word2 of the second file. 

That's the hardest part that got me stuck, 
I think that I need to use some kind of <<stack>> and push words until I find the next word (in this case 'Text' word) and then go backwards (putting "- WORD") up to the first case, where I should put "*"

Comment: @JessiPerotti Okay, I've updated my answer according to your requirement.  I assume that if the first words are different to print "*word1|word2", otherwise it'll print "word1"

Comment: it's not only in case of the first word.
This is what I mean http://prntscr.com/7xu345

Comment: @JessiPerotti Thanks for the screenshot image.  Updated answer I think is what you're looking for then. I would either post that image or explain the diff results in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SetDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] file1 = new String[]{"Some", "Simple", "Text", "File"};
        String[] file2  = new String[]{"Another", "Text", "File", "With", "Additional", "Lines"};
        Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();

        for(String s: file1)
            {
                set1.add(s);
            }

        for(String s2: file2)
            {
                set2.add(s2);
            }

        Set<String> s1intercopy = new HashSet<String>(set1);
        Set<String> s2intercopy = new HashSet<String>(set2);

        s1intercopy.retainAll(s2intercopy); //Finds the intesection                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

        Set<String> s1symdiffcopy = new HashSet<String>(set1);
        Set<String> s2symdiffcopy = new HashSet<String>(set2);

        s1symdiffcopy.removeAll(set2);
        s2symdiffcopy.removeAll(set1);

        int count = 0;
        for(String s7: s1intercopy){
            count++;
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(count)+'.'+s7);
        }
        if (set1.size() > set2.size())
        {
            for(String s3: s1symdiffcopy){
                count++;
                System.out.println(Integer.toString(count)+'.'+'+'+s3);
            }
            for(String s4: s2symdiffcopy){
                count++;
                System.out.println(Integer.toString(count)+'.'+'-'+s4);
            }
        }else if (set2.size() > set1.size())
        {
            for(String s5: s2symdiffcopy){
                count++;
                System.out.println(Integer.toString(count)+'.'+'+'+s5);
            }
            for(String s6: s1symdiffcopy){
                count++;
                System.out.println(Integer.toString(count)+'.'+'-'+s6);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.Text
2.File
3.+Lines
4.+Additional
5.+Another
6.+With
7.-Some
8.-Simple
```

I wasn't sure what you meant by `*Some|Another`, but what the above code does is simply find the intersection and the symmetric differences between the sets, determine which set is bigger, and assign '+' to the values which are part of the bigger set and '-' to those of the smaller set. I didn't read in from a file to save time but that part is easy and you can look that up. It seems based on your output that you were searching through one file and for each string in that file searching through the other file. This is pretty inefficient for large files so I believe the above solution optimizes that by saving it into sets and performing set operations.